# Codenvy stack/library: Can not find the template

Tags: codenvy

The following youtube talks about go stack/liberay Codenvy?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QupRkOqrmQ

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack documentation is here: https://codenvy.com/docs/getting-started/runtime-stacks/index.html

There are examples there and a pointer to the github repo where the dockerfiles / compose files are located.